# collect2: error: ld terminated with signal 11 [Segmentation fault], core dumped

Tags: gcc, segmentation-fault, cygwin, ld

I was learning OpenGL using GLFW, and didn't have a great understanding of makefiles at the time. I had OpenGL working, but I decided to learn makefiles more. I came up with this after a lot of websites, hours, and trial and error:

```
EXENAME = "OpenGL Demo"
CC = gcc
SRCS = ../src/OpenGLDemo.c
OBJS = $(SRCS: .c = .o)
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -c
LIBS = -L./libs -lglfw3 C:/Windows/SysWOW64/opengl32.dll C:/Windows/SysWOW64/glu32.dll

all: opengldemo exe

exe: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) -o $(EXENAME) $(LIBS)

opengldemo: ../src/OpenGLDemo.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) ../src/OpenGLDemo.c

clean:
    rm -f $(EXENAME)

rebuild: clean all
```

But, when I compile, it gives this error when it tries to build the executable:

```
collect2: error: ld terminated with signal 11 [Segmentation fault], core dumped
makefile:11: recipe for target 'exe' failed
make: *** [exe] Error 1
```

It does build an executable, but my computer says it can't run it.
I tried searching the internet, and found gcc bug reports including this error. There is probably something stupid that I am doing to get this error.
How do I fix this error, and what does it mean?

EDIT: Full output:

```
make
gcc -Wall -g -c ../src/OpenGLDemo.c
gcc ../src/OpenGLDemo.c -o "OpenGL Demo" -L./libs -lglfw3
C:/Windows/SysWOW64/opengl32.dll C:/Windows/SysWOW64/glu32.dll
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:/Windows/SysWOW64/opengl32.dll
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/Windows/SysWOW64/opengl32.dll
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
collect2: error: ld terminated with signal 11 [Segmentation fault], core dumped
makefile:11: recipe for target 'exe' failed
make: *** [exe] Error 1
```

Comment: Can you show more of your output, please?

Comment: @CarlNorum That pretty much is the output. I'll add the rest though because you asked.

Comment: `make` should but outputting the commands it's running, at least.

Comment: Did you try fixing that pathname it's warning you about?

Comment: If any part of the toolchain (compiler, linker, make, whatever) crashes it's not the programmer's fault. Whatever stupid things you do, the tools should never crash.

Comment: @CarlNorum I am afraid to because I am compiling on Windows for Windows.

Comment: If I change the pathnames, that warning goes away, but still the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that the `ld` tool or one of its dependencies has a bug which results in an invalid memory access (segmentation fault) on which the operating system kills the process with SIGSEGV (signal 11). It should not crash regardless of your build setup.

You should probably file a bug report for `ld` with your Linux distribution vendor or directly to the vendor of the `ld` tool (usually GNU in case your `ld` tool is from the [GNU binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/)).

Comment: There is no straightforward solution. Either start debugging it or get yourself a new `ld`. But since you seem to be using cygwin both solutions might be problematic. On Linux I'd start debugging by using `strace -f` or `valgrind --track-origins=yes --trace-children=yes` and the like, but on cygwin this might not be an option. However, you're probably more familiar with cygwin than I am.

Comment: I just received a similar error, and can confirm that it is a problem with cygwin. I copied the whole project to a real Linux machine, and everything compiled fine.

Answer (score 9):

I came across exactly the same error.

I'm developing on Windows and Linux at the same time and use Filezilla to transfer my files. The code built previously on Windows with Cygwin, but wouldn't after downloading files from my Linux host.

The process was build on Windows ==> upload to Linux and build ==> make a few changes ==> download to Windows and build ==> get error.

Then it dawned on me I had transferred over the Linux object files with the source, so I erased all the .o files and the build went fine.

I can't say if this was @Zaerospi's problem or not, but it seems to have been the source of my error.

Anyone else with the same error may want to try erasing their object files and rebuilding.

Comment: Perfect thank you. FWIW running the "file" command on .o file for 32-bit cygwin should say ` 80386 COFF executable not stripped ` and for 64-bit cygwin shoudl say `data`.  If they say something else, they may be linux derivated accidentally. A linux 32-bit ex: ` ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped` and 64-bit is similar.